# Show there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}\to 0$ ?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(f_n)$ that converge in measure to $0$, i.e. $$\forall \varepsilon>0, \lim_{n\to \infty }m\{x\mid |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\varepsilon\}=0.$$

Show that there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ that converge pointwise to $0$.

The hint I have is : Use Borel-Cantelli lemma, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $A_n^k=\{x\mid |f_{n}(x)|>\frac{1}{k}\}.$ Since $$\forall k\in\mathbb N^*,\lim_{n\to \infty }m(A_n^k)=0,$$
for all $k$, there is $n_k\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $$m(A_{n_k}^k)<\frac{1}{2^k}.$$
Using Borel-Cantelli, the claim follow.